# How to launch app detail programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want launch another app programmatically in my application.

**for example :** my app have a button and want to launch com.android.chrome but I want this button to launch the chrome app details.

Comment: Check what activities does chrome provide

Comment: charles shiller : You mean? I want launch app details ( application info )

setting - application - aplication details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using action `ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS` as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();    
intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", "<package-name-of-target-app", null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Great! Enjoy coding. BTW I have upvoted your question